# return words spaces numbers or match everything expect special chars like *&$!^&?

Tags: php, regex, filter

ok i have some string

```
'Hello^<php>World&*124><
i ju*st press enteR'
```

how do i return it to ( a function is better ? )

```
'Hello World123
i just press enter'
```

allow

- numbers
- text
- spaces , newline , etc

how do i do that with a regex? do i have to use regex? is there a another way ?

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: You will not be able to find a simple regex that will remove the space in "H ello" but not any other space...

Comment: `H ello` will be a huge problem.

Comment: ups hahaha sorry i forgot that part. :|

Comment: `EnteR` to `enter` is another problem.

Comment: :| no wonder people are voteing up .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function removeBad($str)
{
  return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ (\n|\r\n)]+/", "", $str);
}
```

This will remove anything other than alphabet, numbers, space and newline

If you also want to remove any tags such as `<php>` in your text, you could do:

```
function removeBad($str)
{
  $str = strip_tags($str);
  return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ (\n|\r\n)]+/", "", $str);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$str = removeBad('Hello^<php>World&*124><');
echo $str;
```

**Result:**

```
HelloWorld124
```

.

```
$str = removeBad('i ju*st press EnteR');
echo $str;
```

**Result:**

```
i just press EnteR
```

Comment: great, how about limiting everything ( includeing special chars ) ? 
`/.{$min,$max}/` or is there a better way ?

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: Would you explain a little more what do you mean exactly?

Comment: limiting like 'wadwd' , heres my newbie try hope it help
 
`function setMax( $input , $min , $max ) 
 {
  $text = "/^.{'.$min.','.$max.'}$/";
     if ( preg_match( $text, $input ) )
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }
 }`

Comment: `removeBad('i ju*st press EnteR')` would be `i just press EnteR`, the case of the E and R wouldn't change...

Comment: Note that only `-`, `\ ` and `]` have a special meaning inside character classes. That means `[^a-zA-Z0-9_ (\n|\r\n)]` will also allow `(`, `|`, and `)`.

Comment: @Gumbo: Right you say, so it should be something like `[^a-zA-Z0-9_ \\(\n\\|\r\n\\)]`, right?

Comment: thanks master gumbo, but still i dont know the diffrence betwen (this|that) [this|that]

Comment: @sAc no, you can't have alternation in a character class. `(?!\r?\n)[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]` should work.

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: `(this|that)` is an alternation that matches either `this` or `that`. `[this|that]` on the other hand is a character class that maches one single character of the characters described in `[…]`, in this case either `t`, `h`, `i`, `s`, `|`, or `a`.

Comment: @sAc: An alternative to using a look-ahead assertion would be to use `(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9_ \r\n]+|\r([^\n]))` and replace it with the match of the first group.

Answer (score 0):

Regex substitution can do this for you. I think that you need two. The first one to remove everything between the < and > characters. The second one to remove any character that is NOT in your allowed character set. That is the safest way to do it.